# Get a set of related records from multiple related records laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have `users` that have multiple `restaurants`, then each `restaurant` has `comments`.

So when a `user` logs in, I would like to show a list of all the `comments` from `restaurants` related to the user.

I am using `laravel 5.1`

What I have so far is:

```
$restaurants = $user->restaurants;
        $comments = null;
        foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
            if (!$comments){
              $comments = $restaurants->comments();
            } else{
              $comments = $comments->merge($restaurant->comments());
            }
        }

        $rows = $comments->paginate(15);
        $count = $comments->count();
```

I get a `BadMethodCallException`, I think I am not doing this the laravel way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have u tried Have Many Through? 
**In User model**
    
    `public function user_posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comment', 'App\Restaurant');
    }`

**And in controller u easily to access comments**
   
    `$comments = $user->user_posts();`

More details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Hmm seems to be a problem, `user` to `restaurant` is a `many-to-many` relationship...

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer, to use [`merge`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-merge) the dataset needs to be a `collection`.

So to create the collection you need to use: `->get();`

In my example:

```
$comments = $restaurants->comments()->get();
```

Note: the paginate function has to go, it is nota method of a laravel `Collection`

Comment: You can still do pagination, replace ->get() with ->paginate(15)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost correct, you should have done

```php
$restaurant->comments
// gives you objects
```

instead of

```php
$restaurant->comments()
// gives you query builder
// $restaurants->comments()->get() would also work as someone mentioned
```

as for pagination you can do

```php
$restaurants->comments()->paginate(15)
```

instead of

```php
$restaurants->comments()->get()
```